# Dilemma when create local routes and resovler

Tags: javascript, angular

I have routes defined like this

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CartRoutingModule implements Resolve<ServiceCart> {
  constructor(private service: CartService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const id = route.params['id'] ? route.params['id'] : null;
    if (id) {
      return this.service.find(id).pipe(map((Cart: HttpResponse<ServiceCart>) => Cart.body));
    }

    return of(new ServiceCart());
  }
}

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: CartComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'list', component: ListComponent},
      {path: 'new', component: CartEditComponent, resolve: {Cart: CartRoutingModule}}
    ]
  }];
```

The problem here is I can never get this pass the compiler as `routes` need to defined before `CartRoutingModule` to be used in `@NgModule` as well as `CartRoutingModule` must defined before `routes` as it is a `resolve` in one of the routes

So the compiler throws either

```
TS2448: Block-scoped variable 'routes' used before its declaration.
```

or

```
TS2449: Class 'CartRoutingModule' used before its declaration.
```

then this is like a deadlock

at this point how to use a different annotation or different way to inject route in the context to make compiler happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any specific reason you use **NgModule** as the resolver? Sounds wrong, because NgModels' purpose is configuration, while **Resolver** provides data. You probably want to replace `@NgModel` decorator with `@Injectable` and rename it so it makes sense:

```
@Injectable({provideIn: 'root'}) // or wherever needed
export class CartResolve
```

Comment: I tried to achieve a resolver within the router definition, but I finally give up, defined a separate resolver class to get it over with. Thank you for the answer.